# Why my cog file don't want import to main.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Hi i've tried to wirte my own music bot but aperantly i can't all the time i have problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fabia\Desktop\bot muzyka\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from help_cog import help_cog
  File "C:\Users\fabia\Desktop\bot muzyka\help_cog.py", line 4, in <module>
    class help_cog(commands.cog):
  File "C:\Users\fabia\Desktop\bot muzyka\help_cog.py", line 37, in help_cog
    async def help(self, ctx):
  File "C:\Users\fabia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1748, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "C:\Users\fabia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 381, in __init__
    raise TypeError("Aliases of a command must be a list or a tuple of strings.")
TypeError: Aliases of a command must be a list or a tuple of strings.
```

**This is the error**

No matter what i do can't fix this cog files are in the same folder tried to change few things nothing works if someone could help me that would be awesome here is my code

**Main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os 

from music_cog import music_cog

from help_cog import help_cog

bot = commands.bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

bot.remove_command("help")

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

**music_cog.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
 
#Ustawianie bota
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL.OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnected_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        
        self.vc = None
# szukanie URL na yt 
        def search_yt(Self, item):
            with youtube_dl(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                try:
                    info = ydl.extract_info("ytserch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
                except Exception:
                    return False
                return {'source': info['formats'[0]['url']], 'title': info['title']}
# Nastepna nutka
    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    async def play_music(self, ctx):

        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Nie moge sie podłączyć do kanału")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p"], help="Bot odtwarza piosenek z podanego Linku")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(ArgSpec)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Wejdz na kanal a potem zacznij impreze")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Nie moznna znalezc nutki cos skopales!!!")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Notka dodana do kolejki")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="pauzuje obecnie odtwarzana nutke")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Wznawia zatrzymaną nutke")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help = "Pomija obecnie grana piosenke")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Pokazuje wszystkie obecne nutki w kolejce")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""

        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 4: break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nie ma żadnej nutki w kolejce")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c"], help="Zatrzymuje obecnie grana nutke i czyści całą kolejke")
    async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Kolejka wyczyszczona")
    
    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["l"], help="wyrzuca bota z kanału")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

**help_cog.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class help_cog(commands.cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.help_message = 
"""
Komendy:
!help (!h) - Wyświetla wszystkie dostępne komendy bota
!play <link> (!p) - Wyszukuje nutke na yt i odtwarza ja na twoim kanale 
!pause - Pauzuje obecnie odtwarzana nutke
!clear (!c) - Czyści kolejke
!resume (!r) - Wznawia odtwarzanie muzyki
!skip (!s) - Pomija obecna nutke
!queue (!q) - Pokazuje wszystkie nutki w kolejce
!leave (!l) - Wyrzuca bota z kanału
"""

        self.text_channel_text = []

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                self.text_channel_text.append(channel)

        await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)
    
    async def send_to_all(self, msg):
        for text_channel in self.text_channel_text:
            await text_channel.send(msg)

    @commands.command(name="help", aliases="h", help="Wyświetla wszystkie dostępne komendy bota")
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your help-cog.py your help command has an alias set as "h".

```
@commands.command(name="help", aliases="h", help="Wyświetla wszystkie dostępne komendy bota")
async def help(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```

Like the error says, aliases can only be lists or tuples, yours is a string. Change the command to this.

```
@commands.command(name="help", aliases=["h"], help="Wyświetla wszystkie dostępne komendy bota")
async def help(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```

It's the same thing except the single string that you inputted is now a single string in an array.